# Trying to click n reCAPTCHA

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

I have been trying to submit form here: https://attirealleykurtaset.in/challenge#contact_form

Then I am getting reCAPTCHA and not able to click on with with below code:

```
checkbox=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="recaptcha-anchor"]'))
checkbox.click()
```

The error I am getting is : 'element_to_be_clickable() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given'

Can somebody please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Change the code as below:

```
checkbox=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="recaptcha-anchor"]')))
```

**Notice** the additional parenthesis around `By.XPATH,'//*[@id="recaptcha-anchor"]'`